# how to get visibility back with setVisibility

Tags: java, android, json

In android app i am trying to submit a form having radio button, check box and edit text fields. after submitting the form, it sends the data to j son and then it suppose to have the previous layout.i have used "*setVisibility(View.GONE)*" for hiding data. now my question is how to get the blank form again so that i can make entry in form without going backward.

Comment: set every textView/edittext you need to be blank as textView.setText("");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To visble the view again use `View.Visible` as

`setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

But you want to  blank form details after submitting the form then set `editText` as

```
editText.setText("");
```

And also take `radiobutton,checkbox` etc. to its initial state

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` for get visibility again

or refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) link